# Is there a way to compare the similarity between sentences in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-indexing

Is there a way to compare the similarity between sentences in sql? I have large dataset and I need to identify instances where there are similar words in a two or more setences.

[image]

How do I tell SQL to only return the values below?

[image]

From what I have googled, there may be a way to do this using a Full-Text Search and Semantic Search, but I have been able to find an article that addresses what I am trying to achieve.

Could someone in the group, provide me example or point to an article that could help me? Better yet, is what I am trying to do even achievable in SQL.

Comment: Even being human, I can't understand what is the relation between "today is a great day" and "the person wear red T-shirt". Or I saw too much Star Trek

Comment: There's a lot of research in matching fuzzy text all around the place. I would start by studying the "Levenstein Distance", but there's much more. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance. Btw it's already implemented in Java in Apache Commons.

Comment: Like clause?

SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE Sentence LIKE 'today%' or Sentence LIKE 'the%'

Comment: @Ash Nope, that is jumping at a degenerate edge case and would get you laughed out at an interview. You literally just look up all sentence with a specific word IN THE SENTENCE - that is not even assuming the sentences themselves are similar.

Comment: I was just making a very simple suggestion to try to move things forward a bit. Really, you should use Python, or some equivalent, for something like this. SQL Server is not the right tool for this kind of job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is not.

Part of the problem is that "similarity" is a complex setup and this requires a program to analyze the sentence POSSIBLY with months of programming. You give pretty simplistic examples - grats. Even that is not as easy as you think. What about "the small boy wear red t-shirt" - would small boy be a difference or not?

This requires a LOT of work, and a LOT of definition, or a LOT of training of possibly a multi layer neural network.

SQL generally is awful at string manipulation - the best you get is SOUNDEX and that just compares 4 letters of the first word (RTFM, it is actually QUITE interesting how it works, but it makes it absolutely unsuitable for anything like comparing sentences.

So, no - this is simply way outside the scope of anything in SQL, you will have to download the data and use an out of SQL approach (which is also a LOT more fit for this type of work).

You can obviously work around that with simplistic SQL such as @ASH was suggesting - but this is not looking for "similar sentences" but working around specific markers that ARE SPECIFIC FOR YOUR DATA SET. THis is overfitting and bypassing answering the question you have asked.

Answer (score 0):

You can try SOUNDEX function. Google SOUNDEX  and then understand if this works for your case. The query is:

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE SOUNDEX(Sentence) = SOUNDEX(Sentence);
```

Comment: That is as much illogical tas it can get. I would STRONGLY suggest you read up the documentation on SOUNDEX, then you will realize that it does NOT EVEN LOOK AT THE SENTENCE. It literally only compares 4 letters.